# How to check whether every character is alpha-numeric in PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
preg_match_all("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/",$new_password,$out);
```

The above only checks the 1st character, how to check whether all are alpha-numeric?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php function to determine if a string consist of only alphanumerical characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330215/php-function-to-determine-if-a-string-consist-of-only-alphanumerical-characters)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to use the builtin functions: [ctype_alnum](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

Comment: I'd go with this and avoid the unnecessary overhead of regular expressions.

Comment: +1 The `ctype` functions are surprisingly under-appreciated. :) @casablanca It's easier to read and understand as well.

Comment: Does it depends on any php extention?

Comment: @wamp http://www.php.net/manual/en/ctype.requirements.php No. The `ctype` functions *can* be disabled at compile time, but that's about as likely as `preg_` functions being disabled.

Answer (score 8):

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/", $new_password);
```

This gives `true` if all characters are alphanumeric (but beware of non-english characters). `^` marks the start of the string, and ^$^ marks the end. It also gives `true` if the string is empty. If you require that the string not be empty, you can use the `+` quantifier instead of `*`:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $new_password);
```

Comment: replace + with * if you allow empty strings

Comment: @Yah You're right, I've changed the answer. It's that for an empty string all the characters are alphanumeric (and non-alphanumeric for that matter).

Comment: They're Schrödinger strings! :-O

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this is my solution:

```
<?php
public function alphanum($string){
    if(function_exists('ctype_alnum')){
        $return = ctype_alnum($string);
    }else{
        $return = preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $string) > 0;
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```