# what is the best way to check if string consist of alphanumeric characters only?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php function to determine if a string consist of only alphanumerical characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330215/php-function-to-determine-if-a-string-consist-of-only-alphanumerical-characters)

I need to validate the string using PHP and regexpresisons

string can be min. 4 chars, up to 64 and needs to be only aplphanumeric

all I got so far:

`/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,64}$/`

Comment: what's wrong with the one you have there?

Comment: At first glance, that appears correct.  Please show your real code, and not just the regexp.

Comment: I want it to be bettter, thats all

Comment: @user119096, Better in what way?

Comment: idk, somethign "more correct"? fster?

Comment: And it looks correct. What is not working?

Comment: it's completely correct.  The only shorter option is `\w` but that would also match the underscore character.  You could also make it case insensitive with a `/i` qualifier and then remove one of the `A-Z` lists, but it would probably make it slower.

Comment: 25 days! That's quite some time to figure out your code is just fine. Well, at least you're thorough :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is correct (assuming you only want to match ASCII alphanumerics), so you're probably using it incorrectly. To check whether a string `$subject` matches this regex, use

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{4,64}$/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Note the `/i` option to make the regex case-insensitive. If you also want to match other letters/digits, use `/^[\p{L}\p{N}]{4,64}$/` as your regex.

Comment: nice, acceptinnn soon... explain "so you're probably using it incorrectly" part PLS

Comment: I was under the impression that the regex you had wasn't working. You didn't make it clear in your question that you were just looking for ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{4,64}$/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's about as minimal as you can make it, though it does incur the regex overhad. Anything would would be more complicated, e.g:

```
$str = '....';
if (strlen($str) >= 4) && (strlen($str) <= 64) {
   if (function_to_detect_non_alphanum_chars($str)) {
      ... bad string ...
   }
}
```